# Angular App: How to sync call of multiple views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building an angular single page app, which have a structure like this.

```
"app.parent - parent state"
"app.parent.childState - child state"
"app.parent.childSatate" has 4 multiple named view inside it.
```

I have to show something on parent once all 4 views fetched their respective data.
Any suggestions how to do it?

Note: If Solution is pure independent it helps me alot, if I delete/add any controller then i need not to make changes to parent all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have 4 services that you know will be the data source for 4 different child views.  You can setup your services so that they return references, but still provide access to the underlying promises.  The idea is that you want your views to use the reference when rendering the view; the parent will use $q.all to wait until the individual promises are resolved before it shows something.

**Factories**

```
app.factory('service1', function($http) {
    var data1 = [];
    return {
        promise: $http({...}).success(function(result) {
                     angular.copy(result, data1);
                 }),
        getData: function() {
            return data1;
        }
    }
}); 

app.factory('service2', function($http) {
    var data2 = [];
    return {
        promise: $http({...}).success(function(result) {
                     angular.copy(result, data2);
                 }),
        getData: function() {
            return data2;
        }
    }
}); 
app.factory('service3', function($http) {
    var data3 = [];
    return {
        promise: $http({...}).success(function(result) {
                     angular.copy(result, data3);
                 }),
        getData: function() {
            return data3;
        }
    }
}); 

app.factory('service4', function($http) {
    var data4 = [];
    return {
        promise: $http({...}).success(function(result) {
                     angular.copy(result, data1);
                 }),
        getData: function() {
            return data4;
        }
    }
});
```

**Child Controllers**

```
app.controller('ctrl1', function($scope, service1) {
      $scope.data1 = service1.getData();
});
app.controller('ctrl2', function($scope, service2) {
      $scope.data2 = service2.getData();
});
app.controller('ctrl3', function($scope, service3) {
      $scope.data3 = service3.getData();
});
app.controller('ctrl4', function($scope, service4) {
      $scope.data4 = service4.getData();
});
```

**Parent Controller**

```
app.controller('parent', function($scope, $q, service1, service2, service3, service4) {
     $q.all(
       [service1.promise,
        service2.promise,
        service3.promise,
        service4.promise])
      .then(function() {
           $scope.done = true;
      });
});
```

**Parent View**

```
 <div ng-show="done"> All child data loaded </div>
```

### **A More Modular Approach**

As mentioned in the original post - it would be nice if the parent controller did not have to depend on the injection of the individual data sources. That way, when the child changes data sources (adds sources, or removes sources), the parent controller is not impacted.

This can be done by relying on directive-to-directive communication.  The idea is that the child directives can register their data sources with the parent directive. Once all the data sources have been registered, the parent directive can use $q.all as in the first example.

**Parent Directive**

```
app.directive('parent', function($q) {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         require: 'parent',
         controller: function($scope) {
              $scope.done = false;
              var promises = [];
              this.register = function(promise) {
                  promises.push(promise);
              }
              this.getPromises = function() {
                  return promises;
              }
         },
         link: function(scope, element, attr, parent) {
              $q.all(parent.getPromises())
                  .then(function() {
                      scope.done = true;
                  });
         }
     }
});
```

**Child Directive**

```
app.directive('child', function(service1) {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         require: '^parent',
         controller: function($scope) {
             $scope.data1 = service1.getData();
         },
         link: function(scope, element, attr, parent) {
             parent.register(service1.promise);
         }
     }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div parent>
     <div child>
          <div> {{data1}} </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

### **Yet Another Approach**

You may have noticed that although the second approach does not impact the parent controller, the child controller has a dependency on the parent directive. How can we eliminate this view dependency from the child controller?

Use services.  Create a parent service that allows child controllers to register their promises; and also expose a method from the parent service that returns a promise which is resolved when all the child promises have been resolved.

This may be the preferred approach when you have a single point of loading for the entire page.

**Parent Service**

```
app.factory('parentService', function($q) {
     var promises = [];
     return  {
         promise: function() {
             return $q.all(promises);
         },
         register: function(promise) {
             promises.push(promise);
         }
     }
});
```

**Child Controller**

```
app.controller('childCtrl1', function(parentService, service1) {
     parentService.register(service1.promise);
});

app.controller('childCtrl2', function(parentService, service2) {
     parentService.register(service2.promise);
});
```

**Parent Directive**

```
app.directive('parent', function(parentService) {
      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          controller: function($scope) {
              $scope.done = false;
          },
          link: function(scope) {
              parentService.promise().then(function() {
                  scope.done = true;
              });
          }
      }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div parent>
    <div ng-show="done">All child data loaded</div>
    <div ng-controller="childCtrl1">
         {{ data1 }}
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="childCtrl2">
         {{ data2 }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One more problem i have to resolve, by this approach i have to inject 4 service instances into parent controller. In my case i have 4 controllers, i can't inject controller instances into parent. By this approach if i deleted any of my service then i need to change the parent too. 
Any other approach in which things are more modular and independent ?

Comment: Yes, you can make this more modular by relying on directive-to-directive communication, where child directives register their data sources with the parent directive.  Then in the parent directive's link function, use $q.all.

Comment: Thanks alot , it makes sense using directive.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use $rootScope (recommended factory/service) in all four controllers (for all 4 views), and 
 have certain count/flag which keeps track of data fetching in all controllers and on the main page/controller keep checking for that $rootScope/factory value.

$rootScope/ facetory/services are accessible across controllers/views, so that you can modify in several controllers and access the latest value on some other controller/factory/service.

Related documentations: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 0):

Create a service or factory and inject it into the controllers you need it in, that way you will not have to repeat code.

You can also use this method to share data across your app by making variables avalible via dependency injection.